# R: how to use expand.grid to generate combinations based on group

Tags: r, combinations

I am trying to get all combinations of values per group. I want to prevent combination of values between different groups.

To create all combinations of values (no matter which group the value belongs) vaI can use:

```
expand.grid(value, value)
```

Awaited result should be the subset of result of previous command.

**Example:**

```
#base data
value = c(1,3,5, 1,5,7,9, 2)
group = c("a", "a", "a","b","b","b","b", "c")
base <- data.frame(value, group)

#creating ALL combinations of value
allComb <- expand.grid(base$value, base$value)

#awaited result is subset of allComb. 
#Note: first colums shows the number of row from allComb. 
#Empty rows are separating combinations per group and are shown only for clarification.

       Var1 Var2
1      1    1
2      3    1
3      5    1
11     1    3
12     3    3
13     5    3
21     1    5
22     3    5
23     5    5

34     1    1
35     5    1
36     7    1
37     9    1
44     1    5
45     5    5
46     7    5
47     9    5
54     1    7
55     5    7
56     7    7
57     9    7
64     1    9
65     5    9
66     7    9
67     9    9

78     2    2
```

Comment: `lapply(split(base, base$group), function(i) expand.grid(i$value, i$value))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, quite what I was looking for. Is there a way to return data.frame instead of list?

Comment: Just wrap it with do.call and rbind, i.e. `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(base, base$group), function(i) expand.grid(i$value, i$value)))`